# How can I display an array of objects?

Tags: java

How can I diplay an array of objects of the method **readAllExams(Scanner s)**?? The output should be smth like this:

John Morgan 27 'M' 100

Marcus Sherman 55 'F' 98

......................

But instead I'm getting just index numbers.

```
class Exam {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int ID;
    private char examType;
    private int score;


    public Exam(String firstName, String lastName, int ID, char examType, int score)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.ID = ID;
        this.examType = examType;
        this.score = score;
    }

    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return this.firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName()
    {
        return this.lastName;
    }

    public int getID()
    {
        return this.ID;
    }

    public char getExamType()
    {
        return this.examType;
    }

    public int getScore()
    {
        return this.score;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName + " " + this.ID + " " + this.examType + " " + this.score;
    }

    public boolean equals(Exam object)
    {
        if(this.equals(object))
            return true;

        return false;
    }

}


import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class P2 {

    public static void main(String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {

        Scanner data = new Scanner(new File("Exam.txt"));
        Exam[] readObjects = readAllExams(data);
        //Exam[] collateObjects = collateExams(readObjects);

        for(int i = 0; i < readObjects.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(i);
        }


    }

    public static Exam[] readAllExams(Scanner s) throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    {

        String firstName = "";
        String lastName = "";
        int ID = 0;
        String examType = "";
        char examTypeCasted;
        int score = 0;

        int index = 0;

        Exam[] object = new Exam[50];

        while(s.hasNext())
        {
            //Returns firtsName and lastName 
            firstName = s.next();
            lastName = s.next();

            //Returns ID number
            if(s.hasNextInt())
            {
                ID = s.nextInt();
            }
            else 
                s.next();

            //Returns examType which is 'M' or 'F'
            examType = s.next();
            examTypeCasted = examType.charAt(0);

            if(s.hasNextInt())
            {
                score = s.nextInt();
            }

            object[index] = new Exam(firstName, lastName, ID, examTypeCasted, score);
            //System.out.println();
            index++;
        }
        readExam(s);
        return object;


    }

    public static Exam readExam(Scanner s)
    {
        String firstName = "";
        String lastName = "";
        int ID = 0;
        String examType = "";
        char examTypeCasted = 0;
        int score = 0;

        while (s.hasNext())
        {
            //Returns firtsName and lastName 
            firstName = s.next();
            lastName = s.next();

            //Returns ID number
            if(s.hasNextInt())
            {
                ID = s.nextInt();
            }
            //Returns examType which is 'M' or 'F'
            examType = s.next();
            examTypeCasted = examType.charAt(0);

            if(s.hasNextInt())
            {
                score = s.nextInt();
            }

        }
        Exam temp = new Exam(firstName, lastName, ID, examTypeCasted, score);
        return temp;
    }
```

Comment: Nevermind, folks! I forgot to readObjects[i] in the for loop! Thanks for the attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Arrays` Utility class (e.g. `Arrays.toString(...)`) to display the contents of a whole array, but your `Exam` class needs to overwrite `toString()`.

Example:

```
Exams[] exams = ...
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(exams));
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
System.out.println(i);
```

to

```
System.out.println(readObjects[i]);
```